# Laravel and phpStorm integration - "cannot resolve directory"

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I watched [Jeffrey's video](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15) about how to fix the facades issues. Now, Everything **almost** works perfect.

when I try code on my views for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/page.js"></script>
```

phpStorm marks this location as an error because he cannot resolve the location of the file because he's looking for the file `Root/app/resources/views/layouts/assets/js/page.js` which doesn't exists.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Step 1: Click on the `File Menu`

Step 2: Click on `Settings`, the following image should appear somewhat. (Yours may be different than mine)

[image: Settings window]

Step 3: In the search bar, type `Directories`, see the image:

[image: Type Directories]

Step 4: When you see the `root` of your `project`, click on the it and click on the `Resource Root` to mark it as the root of your project.

Step 5: Click on `Apply`

Step 6: Click on `OK`

And your query will be resolved. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: In the step 4, when I select the folder holding the laravel project as root, the error does not disappear but when I select the public folder, the error does not appear anymore.

Do you guys think that selecting the public folder as root can bring some issues or prevent some functionalities of laravel?

Comment: @Prince You should mark `public` as the root since that's the document root when serving the site. You should reference files within using `/js/app.js` rather than `/resources/js/app.js` in `href` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Change `src="assets/js/page.js"` to `src="{{ asset('assets/js/page.js')}}"`

The assets function is actually a function not a folder. I think it is referencing the expected in the public folder, but I'm still not 100% on that!

Comment: not quite what I asked, and there's no function `assets`, there's `asset` and it doesn't point to the `public/assets/` folder.

Comment: My bad! You actually have an assets folder. Not a huge change. And there isn't you're correct it is asset changing now.

Comment: also yes I apparently misunderstood! glad it worked though!! :D

Comment: correct code is:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/page.js') }}"></script>`
after src use = then "{{ }}"

Comment: @MostafaAsadi thank you. Idk how it has gone this long without that fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('/assets/js/page.js')}}"></script>*
```