# Can not resolve directory "node_modules" in PhpStorm with Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, sass, phpstorm

> PC:Windows 10 V1607.
>   PhpStorm 2016.3.2
>   Build #PS-163.10504.2, built on December 20, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-b15 amd64
>   JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

1. I have already mark "node_modules" as Resource Root in setting.
2. I have cleaned the IDE (PhpStorm) cache and reindex files.

`resources/assets/sass/app.scss` which was built with Laravel still get the inspection "can not resolve the directory "node_modules"".

```
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"; // can't resolve the directory by IDE.
```

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as I've faced the same issue for quite some time.

Comment: According to the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455046/laravel-and-phpstorm-integration-cannot-resolve-directory), the Resource Root should be set to the root of your application, not the `node_modules` directory. Does changing the resource root to be the root of your application fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark project root as Resources Root in `File->Settings->Direcotries`.
If you want to locate the uri in your blade, mark your `project/public` as Resources Root too. 
Hope it could help.

Thanks @patricus

I have received Phpstorm team's same answer about that, and strong recommend to use Jetbrains' JDK instead of Oracle's.

So it is necessary to switch to Jetbrains' JDK build instead of Oracle by following these steps:

1.Go to File | Settings | Plugins > Install JetBrains Plugin
2.Find and install JB SDK Bintray Downloader plugin
3.After the restart, press Ctrl+Shift+A or Help > Find Action
4.Type in "Get JB SDK from BinTray" and press Enter
5.From the list select the latest JDK build - at this moment it is *jbsdk8u112b676_windows_x64.tar.gz* (2017-01-13)
6.Press download, then press Install after it will finish
7.After a restart check that JVM vendor and JRE version are updated in Help > About screen